# Backup Gmail with takeout.google.com but also the labels

Tags: gmail

A few times per year, I backup all my Gmail data with https://takeout.google.com:

[image]

It creates one big file named **"All mail Including Spam and Trash.mbox"**.

It does contain all emails I have, even those which are "Archived", or those which have been moved to labels.

But does it contain the labels information?

I have spent a lot of time organizing/sorting my emails and labelling them.

**Question: Are we sure the labelling applied to each email is kept in this backup archive "All mail Including Spam and Trash.mbox"?**

I've opened this file with `mboxview.exe` freeware and it seems that the answer is No!

**How to backup the labelling too?**

---

PS: There's the option to backup specific labels too in https://takeout.google.com:

[image]

But if we check the checkboxes for labels too, won't the email data be save twice? i.e. **once** in the label backup, and **once** in the `Include all messages in Mail`?

Answer (score 1):

While reading the .mbox with a text editor (supporting multiple GB files!), it seems that there are lines like this:

```
X-Gmail-Labels: Sent,Opened,todo
...
X-Gmail-Labels: Sent,Opened,done
...
X-Gmail-Labels: Sent,Opened,mylabel726
```

I still wonder if it's easily possible to reimport these emails and keep these labels in another Gmail account (in the case there would be a problem with my main Gmail account), or in another IMAP mail system (in the case I would migrate to another provider than Gmail one day).
Comments about this are welcome!